# how to set text field that only accept number and comma (,) in PDF Fillable Form?

Tags: pdf, pdfcreator

i want to set a text field in pdf form that only accept number and comma (,)

for example 
12 or 1,2
so 12 numeric or 1,2 numeric with comma (,)
so the text field can accept number and the text field can accept numeric with comma (,) too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hey i found out how to do it, thanks to mr try67 for the answer

you can use this code

if (event.value) {
    event.rc = /^\d+,?\d*$/.test(event.value) || /,$/.test(event.value);
    if (!event.rc) app.alert("Incorrect value!");
}